# Google DFP returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-dfp, http-status-code-400

trying to get the ad slot working on my site. I ad a set of test slot that were working pretty good, then I removed these and created proper named ones. But now, the request url keep returning NetworkError: 400 bad request...It's about to make me go crazy. I have verified and the url is not outsite the 2k char limit.

I build a little test page that is pretty simple, but its still not showing the ad. I have a default "House" line item ad set in that ad unit but it's just now showing. I can see the iframe in the code but it's empty due the the error.
My normal code is more complex with more ad unit and responsive code, but the test one is really simple:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();

googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/xxxxxxxx/OCR-rightsidebar-skyscraper', [160, 600], 'div-gpt-ad-1414630314403-5').addService(googletag.pubads());
  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();

});

</script>

<body>

<!-- OCR-rightsidebar-skyscraper -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1414630314403-5' style='width:160px; height:600px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1414630314403-5'); });
</script>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there something I don't see here? 
Did anyone ever experienced 400 with pubads.g.doubleclick.net?
Any idea how to solve this?..I searched, but everything I came accross so far was not helpful at all.

Thanks

Comment: I JUST solved this problem on my end and it turned out to be that in my defineSlot() call, the size array I was passing had 'string' elements, ie. ['728','90'] instead of integers [728,90] - which happened because I was passing values from PHP and didn't do an 'intval()' on them.  Might be worth checking.  Once I fixed that my 400 Bad Request errors went away.

Comment: unfortunatly, that won't be the solution in my case. The code is pure js. As we can see in the code snippet on top, the values are transmitted a int value...well it's basicaly the output of the "Generate tag" code of dfp. The only thing I didn't copy over is the gtp tag(first part of the script), that I believe is not changing anyway. Thanks anyway, happy it worked out for you! :)

Comment: Yeah, your code looks fine.  You might want to use this [dfp testing site](http://dfpgpt.appspot.com/) and see what it gives you.  Also, you can try adding `?google_force_console` or `?google_console` to the end of your url and see what the DFP publisher console says about making the calls for the creatives.  Most of the times I've seen 400 Bad Request errors have been related to DFP determining that the size of the space the creative will show in is not large enough and refuses to send the creative. Just a thought.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that but the only thing I get from the console is a warning saying "Ad unit failed to fetch" and everything on the request tab is green. I did take a look at that test site and after inputting the values, the add is empty. Not sure why because there is creatives(160x600) associated to the line item in dfp. Also...did that generator changed the id of the ad?

Comment: hmmm..i am seeing something weird in my dfp account...for some reason, I now see my add unit being children of my "account" id...Like i have an extra ad unit of the main id and then my ad unit a level under...I may have to delete them all and recreate them....

Comment: as  an info I stumble upon this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/dfp/creatives/BOhV4570Tpo
It seems to be a dfp problem. But it's back fro some...and some are still having the problem.